# Using a .Contains in an Object Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an array of objects Accounts, like this:

```
accounts = new[]
{
    new Account
    {
        AccountId = 1,
        Name = "Account 1"
    },
    new Account
    {
        AccountId = 2,
        Name = "Account 2"
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to run this boolean check:

```
var canAccess = _context.Class
         .Where(x => x.Active)
         .Where(x => x.ClassId)
         .Any(x => accounts.Select(y => y.AccountId).Contains(x.AccountId)
```

I verified in our database that there is an existing class that is active and matches the ClassId and also has an AccountId that matches what is in the object array. However, it's not proceeding past that line (and is not providing any useful errors)

Is the syntax that I used valid?

Comment: Is `ClassId` a boolean variable? Since you just check it with `.Where(x => x.ClassId)` instead of something like `.Where(x => x.ClassId == someIdValue)`

Comment: _and is not providing any useful errors_ Is it providing any error? If so, you should post here. If not, you should post a [mre] with a sample input and expected output. Also, you're missing a `);` ate the end.

Comment: You can run the profile and check the query that is being formed

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
 var ids = accounts.Select(x => x.AccountId);
 var canAccess = _context.Class.Select(y => ids.Contains(y.AccountId )).Contains(true);
```

Comment: You'd need to do a `ToList` or `ToArray` on the end to make the `ids` a concreate collection for it to work with EF.

Comment: It is not necessary because accounts is an array of anonymous objects. You should do .ToList() when data comes from database query or if you need that object to be a list. ids is transformed into an IEnumerable <int>. with that select and that should work without .ToList()